# How to numerically verify that principal value?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

Mathematica finds

```
Integrate[Exp[I*s]/(1 + s/(s^2 - 1)^2), {s, -Infinity, Infinity}, PrincipalValue -> True] // ToRadicals
(*A huge closed-form expression which is omitted here.*)
N[%]
(*-1.414 + 0.192275 I*)
```

The use of the principal value is grounded by the plots

```
Plot[{Cos[s]/(1 + s/(s^2 - 1)^2),Sin[s]/(1 + s/(s^2 - 1)^2)},{s,-5,5},WorkingPrecision->30,PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

It's clear that the integrand has its real singularities at the real roots of the denominator,
so

```
sol = Reduce[1 + s/(s^2 - 1)^2 == 0, s, Reals] // ToRadicals;
 sol[[1]][[2]]
(*-(1/(2 Sqrt[3/(4 + (155/2 - (3 Sqrt[849])/2)^(1/3) + (1/2 (155 + 3 Sqrt[849]))^(1/3))]))
 -  1/2 Sqrt[8/3 - 1/3 (155/2 - (3 Sqrt[849])/2)^(1/3) -  1/3 (1/2 (155 + 3 Sqrt[849]))^(1/3) + 
   2 Sqrt[3/( 4 + (155/2 - (3 Sqrt[849])/2)^(1/3) + (1/2 (155 + 3 Sqrt[849]))^(  1/3))]]*)
 N[%]
(*-1.49022*) 
sol[[2]][[2]]
(*-(1/(2 Sqrt[3/(4 + (155/2 - (3 Sqrt[849])/2)^(1/3) + (1/2 (155 + 3 Sqrt[849]))^(1/3))])) +
 1/2 Sqrt[8/3 - 1/3 (155/2 - (3 Sqrt[849])/2)^(1/3) - 
 1/3 (1/2 (155 + 3 Sqrt[849]))^(1/3) + 2 Sqrt[3/( 4 + (155/2 - (3 Sqrt[849])/2)^(1/3)+(1/2 (155 + 3 Sqrt[849]))^( 1/3))]]*)
```

However, I have doubts concerning the obtained principal value because the integrand 
asymptotically equals $\exp(is)$ as $s\to \infty$ and $s\to -\infty$ and 
$$PV\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(is)\,ds $$ does not exist.

In view of it I try to verify it numerically through

```
NIntegrate[Exp[I*s]/(1+s/(s^2-1)^2),{s,-Infinity,
-(1/(2 Sqrt[3/(4+(155/2-(3 Sqrt[849])/2)^(1/3)+(1/2 (155+3 Sqrt[849]))^(1/3))]))-
1/2 Sqrt[8/3-1/3 (155/2-(3 Sqrt[849])/2)^(1/3)-1/3 (1/2 (155+3 Sqrt[849]))^(1/3)+
2 Sqrt[3/(4+(155/2-(3 Sqrt[849])/2)^(1/3)+(1/2 (155+3 Sqrt[849]))^(1/3))]],
-(1/(2 Sqrt[3/(4+(155/2-(3 Sqrt[849])/2)^(1/3)+(1/2 (155+3 Sqrt[849]))^(1/3))]))+
1/2 Sqrt[8/3-1/3 (155/2-(3 Sqrt[849])/2)^(1/3)-1/3 (1/2 (155+3 Sqrt[849]))^(1/3)+
2 Sqrt[3/(4+(155/2-(3 Sqrt[849])/2)^(1/3)+(1/2 (155+3 Sqrt[849]))^(1/3))]],Infinity},
Method->"PrincipalValue",AccuracyGoal->3,PrecisionGoal->3,WorkingPrecision->50]
```

which results in the error message

> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge 
>   to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in s 
>   near {s} = {3.7749613270651398879039428756113970426387939277790*10^28}. 
>   NIntegrate obtained 8.8211977939280824575415993952100374290963331174834*10^47 I and
>    9.1940327832901306869987159913883594088789773626283`50.*^47 for the integral and error estimates.

and

```
 (*-2.6098684408162971553635553440779848277629513026488*10^49 + 
 8.8211977939280824575415993952100374290963331174789*10^47 I*)
```

Constructive suggestions are welcome.

Addition. @b.gates.you.know.what in her/his answer  suggests to use `FourierTransform` to this end. This is not it. Here is an example:

```
Limit[Integrate[Exp[I*t], {t, -a, a}], a -> Infinity]
(*Indeterminate*)
```

but

```
FourierTransform[1, y, t] /. t -> 1

(*0*)
```

-

Comment: `Maple 2020` give me a symbolic solution or using numerics: `-0.998307 - 0.313707 I`.Using FourierTransform in `Mathematica 12.1`- `FourierTransform[1/(1 + s/(s^2 - 1)^2), s, t, 
   FourierParameters -> {1, -1}] /. t -> -1 // ToRadicals` give me also the same output:`-0.998307 - 0.313707 I`.Probably looks like a bug in MMA?

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk: Thank you for your reply. However, neither Maple 2020 nor `FourierTransform` are reliable in this field. BTW, why `t->-1`?

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk:Also the multiplier $\sqrt{2\pi}$ in `FourierTransform` should be taken into account.

Comment: Oh yes it should be: `t=1`,but in this case imaginary part is positive.That is strange in Maple is negative.I am confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the advice by @b3m2a1, I present my answer. Let us substract  `Exp[I*s]` from the integrand. Then

```
a = Integrate[Exp[I*s]/(1 + s/(s^2 - 1)^2) - Exp[I*s], {s, -Infinity, Infinity},
PrincipalValue -> True] // ToRadicals;
N[a,30]
(*-1.41400018802696985500835186883 + 0.19227531358741820427339218093 I*)
```

is in discordance with

```
NIntegrate[Exp[I*s]/(1 + s/(s^2 - 1)^2) - Exp[I*s],{s, -Infinity,
-(1/(2 Sqrt[3/( 4 + (155/2 - (3 Sqrt[849])/2)^(1/3) + (1/2 (155 + 3 Sqrt[849]))^(1/3))])) - 
 1/2 \[Sqrt](8/3 - 1/3 (155/2 - (3 Sqrt[849])/2)^(1/3) - 
 1/3 (1/2 (155 + 3 Sqrt[849]))^(1/3) + 
 2 Sqrt[3/(      4 + (155/2 - (3 Sqrt[849])/2)^(
   1/3) + (1/2 (155 + 3 Sqrt[849]))^(1/3))]),
-(1/(2 Sqrt[3/(   4 + (155/2 - (3 Sqrt[849])/2)^(1/3) + (1/2 (155 + 3 Sqrt[849]))^(
1/3))])) + 1/2 \[Sqrt](8/3 - 1/3 (155/2 - (3 Sqrt[849])/2)^(1/3) - 
 1/3 (1/2 (155 + 3 Sqrt[849]))^(1/3) + 
 2 Sqrt[3/(4 + (155/2 - (3 Sqrt[849])/2)^(
   1/3) + (1/2 (155 + 3 Sqrt[849]))^(1/3))]),Infinity},
Method -> "PrincipalValue", WorkingPrecision -> 40, AccuracyGoal -> 7, PrecisionGoal -> 7]
(*-0.9983073697207267431817361195580732660872 - .313706787296245329692113892146598026371 I*)
```

Therefore, at least one of the above results in not correct.
However, the latter result is in accordance with the modified approach by @b.gates.you.know.what :

```
den[s_] = 1 + s/(s^2 - 1)^2;
f[s_] = Exp[I s]/den[s] - Exp[I*s];
integ = Sqrt[2 Pi] Limit[FourierTransform[1/den[s] - 1, s, k], k -> 1];
integ // N
(*-0.998307 - 0.313707 I*)
```

The above result can be grounded by the calculation with the residues (Here the Jordan's lemma is applicable: pay your attention to `-Exp[I*s]` in the definition of `f[s_]`.).

Conclusion: (i) Because $$PV\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(is)\,ds $$ does not exist, the principal value of the integral under consideration in the question does not exist too. (ii) The symbolic result  produced by the `Integrate` command with the `PrincipalValue->True` option is not correct.

Answer (score 8):

As noted by the user Mariusz Iwaniuk one could use:

```
den[s_] = 1 + s/(s^2 - 1)^2;
f[s_] = Exp[I s] / den[s];
integ = Sqrt[2 Pi] Limit[FourierTransform[1/den[s], s, k], k -> 1];
integ // N
(* -0.998307 - 0.313707 I *)
```

As a check one could try using residues:

```
zeros = Solve[den[s] == 0 + I 0, s];
residues = Residue[f[s], {s, #}] & /@ zeros[[All, 1, 2]];

2 Pi I (1/2 residues[[1]] + 1/2 residues[[2]] + residues[[4]]) // N
(* -0.998307 - 0.313707 I *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your work.  BTW, your `f[s]` is not defined at all. Do I correctly understand that you suggest a different approach to the integral under consideration?

Comment: @user64494 Added the missing definition, thank you. I was just trying to understand how the result via Fourier transform might be obtained.

Comment: I changed my mind and deleted -1. You wrote " I was just trying to understand how the result via Fourier transform might be obtained.". BTW, how can  your result be confirmed by numeric integration?

Comment: I changed my mind again. The question is whether does this Fourier transform exist at all? It certainly does not exist in classical sense since the integrand is not absolutely integrable over the reals. Of course, one may formally count residues, but does it make any sense?

Comment: Here is a simpler version of the problem: `Limit[Integrate[Exp[I*t], {t, -a, a}], a -> Infinity]` in undeterminated, but `FourierTransform[1, y, t] /. t -> 1` produces `0`.

Comment: The calculation of the integral of `f[s]` over the reals by its residues is not valid since the Jordan's lemma (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma) is not applicable here.

Comment: Moreover, `Integrate[ComplexExpand[Exp[I*r*Exp[I*t]]]*r, {t, 0, Pi}, 
 Assumptions -> r > 0]` produces `r (\[Pi] - 2 SinIntegral[r])` and `Limit[RealAbs[r (\[Pi] - 2 SinIntegral[r])], r -> Infinity]` performs `Indeterminate`. The knockout punch.

Comment: I'd like to add `MaxLimit[RealAbs[r (\[Pi] - 2 SinIntegral[r])], r -> Infinity]` produces `2`, no more and no less.

Comment: Adjustment.  The integral `Integrate[ComplexExpand[Exp[I*r*Exp[I*t]]]*r, {t, 0, Pi},   Assumptions -> r > 0]` in the above comment of me  shold be replaced by `Integrate[Exp[I*r*Exp[I*t]]*r*Exp[I*t], {t, 0, Pi}, 
 Assumptions -> r > 0]` which equals `2 I Sin[r]`. This does not change the matter.