# How to write down that WhenEvent?

Tags: differential-equations

I am translating [that nice animation of a ball bouncing on a hilly terrain](https://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=154003) 
(can be downloaded as a PDF file and as  [a GIF file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q9mnz46tyf2az77/view.gif?dl=0)) from Maple language into Wolfram Language.
Here is my code.

```
surf = Sin[x] + 0.2*Cos[4 x + Sin[4 x]] - 0.2*x + 3;
Plot[surf, {x, 0, 10}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
n = Normalize[{D[surf, x], 1}] /. x -> x[t];v = {x'[t], y'[t]};c = 0.99;
vreflect = -(1 + c)*v.n*n + v // Simplify;
deq = {y''[t] == -9.81, x''[t] == 0, x[0] == 2, y[0] == 4.5,x'[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0};
NDSolve[{Evaluate[deq], WhenEvent[Evaluate[y[t] == surf /. x -> x[t]], {y'[t] -> vreflect[[2]], 
x'[t] -> vreflect[[1]]}]}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

However, the latest command produces an error. I need to tronslate the code of Maple `events = [[y(t) = eval(surf, x = x(t)), [temp = diff(x(t), t), diff(x(t), t) = V_reflect[1], diff(y(t), t) = subs(diff(x(t), t) = temp, V_reflect[2])]]]`, where the derivative `diff(x(t), t)` is saved and used twice, into Wolfram Language.

Comment: The downvoter: Can you ground your vote? TIA.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but currently the question doesn't _look like_ a self-contained one 
 i.e. it _seems_ that answerers have to read an external PDF file (involving Maple code! ) to understand the whole question. Explaining the system with traditional math notation first and then showing the unworking code may be better.

Answer (score 13):

The following *Mathematica* workflow shows that it tracks the *Maple* solution quite well if one decreases `MaxStepFraction` (other simulation parameters may also work).

## Workflow

### Create Bounce Function

```
(* Hilly surface *)
surf[x_] := Sin[x] + 1/5*Cos[4 x + Sin[4 x]] - 1/5*x + 3;
(* Calculate normal using FrenetSerretSystem *)
{tangent[x_], normal[x_]} = Last@FrenetSerretSystem[{x, surf[x]}, x];
(* Create bounce function from Maple PDF *)
vbounce[vx_, vy_, {nx_, ny_}, 
   cor_ : 0.99] = (-(1 + cor) ({vx, vy}.{nx, ny}) {nx, ny} + {vx, 
      vy}) // Simplify;
```

### Setup and Solve ODE

```
(* Hill plot *)
hill = Plot[surf[x], {x, 0, 10}, AspectRatio -> Automatic];
(* Setup and solve diffeq system *)
g = -9.81;
c = 0.99;
tend = 10;
deq = {y''[t] == g, x''[t] == 0, x[0] == 2, y[0] == 4.5, x'[0] == 0, 
   y'[0] == 0};
{xfun, yfun} = 
  NDSolveValue[{deq, 
    WhenEvent[
     y[t] == surf[x[t]], {{x'[t], y'[t]} -> 
       vbounce[x'[t], y'[t], normal[x[t]], c]}]}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 
    tend}, MaxStepFraction -> 1/2000];
```

### Import Images from Dropbox Link

```
(* Import gif image from Dropbox download *)
gif = Import["view.gif"];
```

### Create Manipulate to Compare *Maple* and *Mathematica*

```
(* Create manipulate for comparison purposes *)
grids[min_, max_] := 
 Join[Range[Ceiling[min], Floor[max]], 
  Table[{j + .5, Dashed}, {j, Round[min], Round[max - 1], 1}]]
frames = Table[
   Rasterize@
    Show[{Graphics[{Blue, PointSize[Large], 
        Point[{{xfun[t], yfun[t]}}]}], hill}, 
     PlotLabel -> 
      Style[StringTemplate["Time = ``"][
        ToString@PaddedForm[t, {6, 4}]], 14], 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 5}}, Axes -> True, 
     GridLines -> grids], {t, 0, tend, 0.067114}];
Manipulate[Column[{frames[[i]], gif[[i]]}], {i, 1, 150, 1}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

[image: Manipulate]

### Animation

```
(* Create Comparison Animation *)
cols = Table[Column[{frames[[i]], gif[[i]]}], {i, 1, 150}];
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
Export["bounce.gif", cols[[1 ;; 100]], 
 "AnimationRepetitions" -> ∞]
```

[image: Animation]

Comment: +1. Many thanks from me to you for your work. You are a Mathematica master! First, do you mean ODE instead of PDE? Second, `gif = Import["view.gif"]` does not work for me (perhaps, some path should be added). Third, can you extend both the animations to 20 sec? Fourth, a good code is a commented code (Comments are useful for the author as well for  the reader.). In order to approve your answer, can you kindly respond my requests?

Comment: `gif = Import[
  https : // www.dropbox.com/s/q9mnz46tyf2az77/view.gif?dl = 0, 
  "view.gif"]` does not work too.

Comment: If I extend the time in the Maple application to `t = 0 .. 150`, then the ball falls. Also ( if I am not mistaken)  the result of `...{t, 0, tend, 0.5}];
Manipulate[Column[{frames[[i]]}], {i, 1, 150, 1}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Top]` with `tend = 150;` differes from the Maple's one in this case

Comment: @user64494 I had to download the gif file manually from the Dropbox and I put it in the saved notebook directory.   You probably could transfer the file to your own personal Dropbox location and import using Insert>FilePath.  The way I synched the two simulation was I counted the number of frames in the gif animation and I set the increment to timestamp I observed in `gif[[2]]`.  You will have to do the same to sync the timestamps.  Also note, the gif animations are limited to 2MB on this site, which limits how many frames you can show.

Comment: Tim Laska, thank you. How about `tend = 150;` and the comments?

Comment: Tim Laska: Put `c = 0.8;` and see the result of `Manipulate[Column[{frames[[i]]}], {i, 1, 150, 1}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Top]` where the ball falls too.

Comment: @user64494 Have you chosen a smaller `MaxStepFraction` for `tend=150`? BTW I think adjusting `MaxStepSize` may be a better choice in this case.

Comment: @user64494 I think that you are substantially moving the goal post from your initial question from getting a particular simulation to work to one that is a general robust solution to a large parameter space.  I agree with @xzczd's comment about MaxStepSize since you are interested in increasing tend 15x.  You should also look at the [Possible Issues>Arbitrarily close events](https://wolfram.com/xid/0b8empjuoy-gyu6lv), which happens when the particle slows down to near zero velocity.  To get $tend=150$ to work, try `MaxStepSize -> 1/200, WorkingPrecision -> 50, MaxSteps -> Infinity`

Comment: Tim Laska, thank you for your reply and added comments. The comments to the `WhenEvent` command are sill required.

Answer (score 8):

The problems lies in the original code:

1. wrong tangent vector(maybe you were trying normal vector)
2. redundant or invalid `Evaluate`

---

I rewrote the code:

```
Clear@"`*"
surf[x_] := Sin[x] + 0.2*Cos[4 x + Sin[4 x]] - 0.2*x + 3;
hill = Plot[surf@x, {x, 0, 10}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
n = Normalize@{1, surf'[x[t]]};
v = {x'[t], y'[t]};
c = 0.8;
vreflect = (1+c)*Projection[v, n] - v //Simplify;
deq = {y''[t] == -9.81, x''[t] == 0, x[0] == 2, y[0] == 4.5, x'[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0};
sol = Reap@NDSolve[
    {
        deq,
        WhenEvent[
            y[t] <= surf@x[t],
            {
                {x'[t], y'[t]} -> (Sow@{x[t],y[t]};#)
            }
        ]&@vreflect,
        WhenEvent[
            x[t] > 10 || x[t] < 0,
            tmax=t;"StopIntegration"
        ]
    }
, {x, y}
, {t, 0, 10}
, MaxStepSize -> 0.0001];
If[!ValueQ@tmax,tmax=10];
Show[
    ParametricPlot[{x@t, y@t} /. sol[[1,1]], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> {{0,10},{0,4.5}}],
    hill,
    Graphics@Point@sol[[2,1]]
]
```

[image: Final effect]

---

If you want the dissipation to be with the normal component instead of the tangent component, the formula should be:

```
vreflect = (1+c)*Projection[v, n] - c*v //Simplify;
```

But the ball will be no longer energetic. The collision will be frequent and difficult to be detect.

Comment: I wonder the upvoter, though here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/223847/how-to-numerically-verify-that-principal-value I see 7 votes for the wrong answer.

Comment: Here is my comment, deleted by an unknown to me person. Thank you for your work. A good code is a commented code. There are comments in the Maple application, but there aren't comments to your code. First, this is not an animation. Second, your result differs from the result in the application. Third, your "wrong tangent vector" is ungrounded.

Comment: Put `c=0.8` in your code and explain the result. TIA.

Comment: @user64494 Both of you have defined the normal vector in wrong way… Just plot it: `origin = {x, surf};

nvec = Normalize[{D[surf, x], 1}];

arrow[x_] = {origin, origin + nvec};

Manipulate[plot~Show~Graphics[Arrow@arrow@x], {x, 0, 10}]`. The correct normal vector is `nvec = Normalize[{-D[surf, x], 1}];`.

Comment: @xzczd I am not using normal vectors but tagent vectors.

Comment: @user64494 To get correct picture, lowering the `MaxStepFraction` is okay. Besides, there're some problems that is unimportant and easy to fix, they're fixed in my edit.

Comment: …How can tagent vector be used for solving the problem?

Comment: @xzczd As `normal comp + tangent comp = original`, this choice doesn't matter besides the change of the formula.

Comment: But the reference answer shown in the GIF will be reproduced only if `n` is the normal vector and `vreflect = -(1 + c)*v.n*n + v` is used.

Comment: @xzczd I am lazy to download that PDF. I thought that showing the two problems is enough.

Comment: @xzczd In fact, I made an mistake. My previous formula put the dissipation with the tangent component. If it is with the normal component, the issue of "Arbitrarily close events" which is mentioned by another answer will appear.

Comment: Also, "redundant or invalid `Evaluate`", though the first `Evaluate` is redundant, the second `Evaluate` is not invalid. The real problem is one need one more `Evaluate` for the _action_ of `WhenEvent` i.e. `WhenEvent[Evaluate[y[t] == surf /. x -> x[t]], {x'[t], y'[t]} -> vreflect // Evaluate]`. (The _action_ needs to be corrected of course. )

Comment: @xzczd You are right. I skimmed the code so fast that the second `Evaluate` was recognized to be in a deeper level.

Comment: Thank you for your edit though the picture is not edited. Comments are still required, especially to the `WhenEvent` command, in order to accept your answer.

Comment: @user64494 If you're confused about the `{x'[t], y'[t]} -> vreflect`, this is discussed in **Possible Issues** section of document of `WhenEvent`, starting from the line _With sequential event actions, the variables are modified in turn…_.

Answer (score 3):

Here we provided a 3D version.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
reflect[vector_, 
   normal_] = -(vector - 2 (vector - Projection[vector, normal]));
f[x_, y_, z_] = z - Sin[y*Sin[x]];
g[x_, y_, z_] = x^2/4^2 + y^2/3^2 + z^2/8^2 - 1;
(*reg=ImplicitRegion[g[x,y,z]<=0,{x,y,z}];*)

reg = Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {4, 3, 8}];
surfs = ContourPlot3D[f[x, y, z] == 0, {x, y, z} \[Element] reg, 
   Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> Darker@Cyan, 
   RegionBoundaryStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[.1], Opacity[.1]], 
   BoxRatios -> Automatic, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False];

pt0 = {.5, .5, 6};
dir0 = {0, 0, 0};
sol = NDSolveValue[{x''[t] == 0, y''[t] == 0, 
    z''[t] == -9.8, {x[0], y[0], z[0]} == pt0, {x'[0], y'[0], z'[0]} ==
      dir0,
    WhenEvent[
     f[x[t], y[t], z[t]] == 
      0, {{x'[t], y'[t], z'[t]} -> 
       reflect[{x'[t], y'[t], 
         z'[t]}, {Derivative[1, 0, 0][f][x[t], y[t], z[t]], 
         Derivative[0, 1, 0][f][x[t], y[t], z[t]], 
         Derivative[0, 0, 1][f][x[t], y[t], z[t]]}]}], 
    WhenEvent[
     g[x[t], y[t], z[t]] == 
      0, {{x'[t], y'[t], z'[t]} -> 
       reflect[{x'[t], y'[t], 
         z'[t]}, {Derivative[1, 0, 0][g][x[t], y[t], z[t]], 
         Derivative[0, 1, 0][g][x[t], y[t], z[t]], 
         Derivative[0, 0, 1][g][x[t], y[t], z[t]]}]}]},
   {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, 15}, MaxStepSize -> .01];
ani = Animate[Show[surfs,
   ParametricPlot3D[sol, {t, 0, c}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.5], Yellow], Mesh -> {{c}}, 
     Method -> {"BoundaryOffset" -> False}, 
     MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[1], AbsolutePointSize[10]]] /. 
    Line -> Arrow, PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, 
   ImageSize -> Large], {c, $MachineEpsilon, 15}, 
  ControlPlacement -> Bottom, AnimationRate -> 1]
```

[image]